# How to remove an XML declaration + root tag from string or xml

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have an XML with xml declaration + root tag , which i don't need 
 -> my goal is convert it to JSON, without xml declaration and root tag

```javascript
var xml = XDocument.Parse(renderedOutput);
var xmlWithoutRoot = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
// convert XML to JSON
var newJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlWithoutRoot);
```

How can i remove the XML deceleration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from the xml, before serialize it to JSON?

Comment: Why are you serializing XML (presumably as a single massive string) within JSON?

Comment: i have an xml , and i need it to be in json format, what do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For removing XML declaration, you can use `XElement` instead of `XDocument`, for example :

```cs
var renderedOutput = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
  <root>
   <foo>bar</foo>
 </root>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(renderedOutput);
var xmlWithoutRoot = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
// convert XML to JSON
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlWithoutRoot);
Console.WriteLine(newJson);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ccxdK)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

Comment: Ok i am a bit late to the party but why would you serialize this twice. If you remove your var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlWithoutRoot); you are fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/BGtPlL is your revised sample